# jquery.animate callback appending twice

Tags: jquery, animation, append

I'm using animate and append to do some animation, delete some html dynamically and then append some new html following the animation. For some reasons the appending function is being called twice, which is quite undesirable. Why?

(I'm using bootstrap, hence the col-9 class)

```
    function manageWeather(){

        //fade-out effect from loading interface
        $(".gif-container, .text-container").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000, function(){
            //$(".row-change1").remove();
            $(this).remove(resizeMainContainer());
        });

        //jQueryUI function to animate the main-container resize
        function resizeMainContainer(){
            $(".main-container").animate({
                height: "80%"
            });
            $(".main-container").switchClass("col", "col-9", addElements());
        }

        //adding columns to row
        function addElements(){
            $(".row-change1").append("<div class='col-2'>col2</div>")
            $(".row-change1").append("<div class='col-9'>col9</div>")
            $(".row-change1").append("<div class='col-1'>col1</div>")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that the first animate function has two elements, which means that the callback functions are then called twice twice, once for the gif-container and once for the text-container.

The correct way to do it would be to separate them, and put the callback function in just the last one like this:

```
$(".gif-container").animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 1000, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});

$(".text-container").animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 1000, function(){
    $(this).remove(resizeMainContainer());
});
```